# Group by previous date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the min and max rows per group with a End Date matching the next rows Begin Date

Input Date:

```
ResultUid   BeginDate                 EndDate
1           1999-12-31 00:00:00.000   2000-01-31 00:00:00.000
1           2000-01-31 00:00:00.000   2000-02-29 00:00:00.000
1           2000-02-29 00:00:00.000   2000-03-31 00:00:00.000
1           2000-03-31 00:00:00.000   2000-04-30 00:00:00.000
1           2007-03-31 00:00:00.000   2007-04-30 00:00:00.000
1           2007-04-30 00:00:00.000   2007-05-31 00:00:00.000
1           2007-05-31 00:00:00.000   2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

Desired Result:

```
ResultUid   BeginDate                 EndDate
1           1999-12-31 00:00:00.000   2000-04-30 00:00:00.000
1           2007-03-31 00:00:00.000   2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT
    ResultUid, 
    MIN(BeginDate) AS "min", 
    MAX(EndDate) AS "max", 
    lag
FROM (
    SELECT
        ResultUid, 
        BeginDate, 
        EndDate, 
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,lag(BeginDate) OVER (order by EndDate), EndDate) AS "lag"
    FROM Results
    GROUP BY
        ResultUid, 
        BeginDate, 
        EndDate
) sub
GROUP BY
    ResultUid, 
    lag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine where a group starts by checking the previous end date.  Then, the groups of adjacent dates can be assigned a group id by taking a cumulative sum:

```
select resultuid, min(begindate) as begindate, max(enddate) as enddate
from (select r.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate = begindate then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by resultuid order by begindate) as grp
      from (select r.*,
                   lag(enddate) over (partition by resultuid order by begindate) as prev_enddate
            from results r
           ) r
     ) r
group by resultuid, grp;
```